# Delphi TAction intercepts hot keys before focused TEdit

Tags: delphi, vcl

I have VCL form with some actions and TEdit control. I assigned hot key BACKSPACE for one TAction, and if this TAction (if enabled) intercepts BACKSPACE before focused TEdit, thus this button becomes unavailable for editing text there. How to resolve this problem?

I found one solution - on OnEnter event of TEdit disable TActions associated with editing keys, on OnExit event enable them again. But probably there is better solution.

Comment: Don't use BACKSPACE as a shortcut for the TAction. Backspace is a normal text editing key, and you shouldn't use those keys as a shortcut without a modifier. Ctrl+Backspace is good, Alt+Backspace is good, Ctrl+Alt+Backspace is good. Backspace alone  is not. Neither is assigning A, B, C, left-arrow, right-arrow, up-arrow or down-arrow without a modifier. Ctrl+C is a good shortcut. C by itself is not.

Comment: You might also find this interesting reading: [A Key’s Odyssey](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/38447). It explains how the VCL processes and dispatches keyboard messages.

Comment: I need to use backspace for some reasons, also I use space to and may use other buttons. My main form had no editing fields before and users used to use such keys. It is faster than combinations.

Comment: Of course the action intercepts the key before any control does, what would be a shortcut good for if it didn't work.